# How to fix Flexslider height issue

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have integrated Flexslider. Everything is running good but when page loads first time then it takes so much height and then control dots goes to very down but when I click on dots then dots comes up. Please help me to fix the animation of the height in first load.

Here is the script:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if (jQuery('.flexslider').length > 0) {
        jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animateHeight: false,
            smoothHeight: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add a working example. You can add a working example if you click next to the image icon in the editor.

Comment: One of the worpress plugin lazy load was conflicting with Flex slider images. Its done now. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Glad you solved it :)